# Thread Locking in Large Parralel Applications

Tags: multithreading, architecture, parallel-processing

I have a slightly more general question about parallelisation and threadlocking synchronization in large applications. I am working on an application with a large number of object types with a deep architecture that also utilises parallelisation of most key tasks. At present synchronisation is done with thread locking management inside each object of the system. The problem is that the locking scope is only as large as each object, whereas the object attibutes are being passed through many different objects where the attributes are losing synchronisation protection.

What is best-practice on thread management, 'synchronization contexts' &c. in large applications? It seems the only foolproof solution is to make data synchronization application wide such that data can be consumed safely by any object at any time, but this seems to violate object oriented coding concepts.

How is this problem best managed?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to make your objects read-only; a read-only object doesn't need any synchronization because there is no chance of any thread reading it while another thread writes to it (because no thread ever writes to it).  Object lifetime issues can be handled using lock-free reference counting (using atomic-counters for thread safety).

Of course the down side is that if you actually want to change an object's state you can't; you have to create a new object that is a copy of the old object except for the changed part.  Depending on what your application does, that overhead may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: The system involves high frequency consumption and invalidation of property values so maintaining references would be preferred. The thread management within objects is fine but say when one thread is wanting to invalidate a property, it goes through the correct channels in the object, but when the value is consumed for for instance updating the view, the only way to be thread safe is to have the view participate in the locking mechanism of the underlying objects, which means it can't be agnostic to their structure.

Comment: _ Are there any valid patterns where the lock objects are publicly exposed?